# Export Mapbox-Studio project to Mapnik XML

Tags: mapnik, mapbox

Tilemill had a feature to export the project to Mapnik XML (see [here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/exporting/#mapnik-xml-export)). Is there an equivalent functionality in [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/)?

*Some background:* I'm trying to use a style like [OSM Bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright), edit it a little and the use in on my own tileserver (running mapnik).

Comment: It's been some time Matthias. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Synesso No Sir, I never found a solution to this.